# Saving kendo grid at once, not row by row

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid where all fields are required. The grid has several rows and when I click save button, it tries to save each row one by one. If some rows have empty values, then I receive as much alert messages as the count of rows. Is there a way to get the alert message only once and stop attempts to save other rows until data will be provided as required?

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]MyReport report)
    {
        CheckNullValues(report.ID); //here alert is thrown

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        await ReportsRepository.CreateObjectSmartAsync(report.GetPOCO());
        return Created(report);            
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

set `batch: true` in your dataSource.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-batch

Edit: I understood the question wrongly. Before sending data to server, you can do your validations client-side by iterating through grid.dataSource.data(). If validations are satisfying, you can call the grid saveChanges method.